# changing sizes of boot partitions

Tags: boot

My boot is too small..should have made it larger initially.  So, I have rebooted the machine with the Elementary/USB drive.  Launched GPartition.  Unmounted the partitions on my HD.  But I can't seem to change the size of the partitions.  /dev/sda is 298.09 Gib...I would like to shrink it by 10 GB or so.  Then I will add those 10 GB to my boot volume. My boot volume is /dev/sda1 and is only 243 mib But I am unable to make it happen.  The partitions on the HD are definitely unmounted.  I cannot drag the bar to decrease the size of /dev/sda.  It does not move.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well ... not sure if this will help ... because what you typed may just be a typo on your part.
But assuming that /dev/sda IS your hard disk
you CANNOT make that bigger (unless you are a magician)
what you can do is change partition sizes.
Partitions names will look like

1. /dev/sda1
2. /dev/sda2
   etcetera

Just remember ... the partition must be contiguous space on the disk
(well unless you are using LVM or btrfs) ... in which case your question is not giving enough information for someone to help you.

Now if you don't have the space on the disk to move and re-size partitions ... you may be better off using clonezilla to copy your entire disk off ... re-partition your drive .... then use clonezilla to restore with resized partitions ... I have just done that to transfer files from a disk reporting SMART errors to a new one ... worked like a champ.

Comment: Well I gave up an just reinstalled Elementary.   

/dev/sda1 is the boot and is 243 MiB.   So that would be the first partition?

/dev/sda2 (and /dev/sda5) is 297.85 GiB - second partition I assume.

but it looks like I will have the same issue again...the boot partition is too small.  It will eventually fill up with old kernels etc when I do updates.

I would guess I need to make the boot partition larger.  To do that I would need to shrink the /dev/sda2.  So I would like to shrink sda2 by about 10 GiB and add those 10 GiB to sda/1 (the boot partition).  How do I do that?

Comment: /boot is used for the initial boot of the system .. and is not really used after that ... most distros that I have installed tend to make this partition 500MB ... but I prefer 1 GB which is PLENTY of room for kernels, GRUB, etc ... You should not need more than that

Answer (score 1):

So, you have an installation you're not willing to remove? If you are able to remove the stuff you installed, you can just delete all the partitions and then create new ones. Note that, if you want to split the disk into many partitions, the biggest ones should be `/home` (where all your user-created stuff goes) and `/opt` (where most of the installed programs go).